# Adding randomized headers in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I would like to add an "X-Slogan" header to Apache's responses set to a value chosen at random from a list of strings. The best solution I've been able to come up with so far is to rotate through the strings based on TIME_SEC, e.g.

```
UnsetEnv HEAD_X_SLOGAN_1
UnsetEnv HEAD_X_SLOGAN_2
UnsetEnv HEAD_X_SLOGAN_3
UnsetEnv HEAD_X_SLOGAN_4

RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} <15
RewriteRule . - [env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN_1:%{TIME_SEC},last]

RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} >14
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} <30
RewriteRule . - [env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN_2:%{TIME_SEC},last]

RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} >29
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} <45
RewriteRule . - [env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN_3:%{TIME_SEC},last]

RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} >44
RewriteRule . - [env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN_4:%{TIME_SEC},last]

Header set X-Slogan "Palm trees" env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN_1
Header set X-Slogan "Oranges" env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN_2
Header set X-Slogan "Shoes" env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN_3
Header set X-Slogan "Velociraptors" env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN_4
```

However, this isn't really random. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_rewrite has a MapType of rnd which may be able to do what you want.

See [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) under randomized plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dennis I arrived at the following solution:

Apache config:

```
# Set a rotating slogan.

# Contents need to match the RewriteConds below.
RewriteMap slogans rnd:/web/www.wireshark.org/slogans.txt
RewriteRule . - [env=SLOGAN_NUM:${slogans:num}]

RewriteCond %{ENV:SLOGAN_NUM} =1
RewriteRule . - "[env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN:Slogan 1.,last]"

RewriteCond %{ENV:SLOGAN_NUM} =2
RewriteRule . - "[env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN:Slogan 2.,last]"

RewriteCond %{ENV:SLOGAN_NUM} =3
RewriteRule . - "[env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN:Slogan 3.,last]"

RewriteCond %{ENV:SLOGAN_NUM} =4
RewriteRule . - "[env=HEAD_X_SLOGAN:Slogan 4.,last]"

Header set X-Slogan "%{HEAD_X_SLOGAN}e"
```

slogans.txt:

```
#
# Randomized slogan numbers
# Need to match the slogans in the Apache config.
#
num 1|2|3|4
```

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you. I had kind of envisioned the slogans being in the text file instead of indexes and you'd just have one rewrite rule.

Comment: I tried adding them to the file initially. It only parsed up to the first space, even when wrapped in quotes. There's no doubt a cleaner way to do this but I'm happy that it works.

Comment: You might try escaping the spaces instead of using quotes: `slogan Slogan\ 1|Slogan\ 2`